# PHP if/else shorthand notation - multiple conditions

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Please consider the follwing code construction:

```
condition  ? code_if_true  : 
condition2 ? code_if_true2 : 
             code_if_false;
```

This doesn't work for PHP whereas it does for JavaScript.

Is there a way to get this working for PHP?

Comment: how is it not working? what is the error?

Comment: It does work in PHP. What is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than "It doesn't work".  And using this shorthand with anything that depends on complex logic is only going to make your code unreadable anyway.  You're much better off using nested if statements.

Comment: It does work in PHP, but [not the same way](http://us.php.net/ternary#example-121) as it does in JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PHP, the conditional operator is [***left***-associative<sup>[PHP.net]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#language.operators.precedence), compared to virtually all other languages where it is right-associative.

That's why you need to use parentheses to control the order of evaluation<sup>1</sup>:

```
 condition  ? code_if_true  : 
(condition2 ? code_if_true2 : 
              code_if_false );
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>The order in which which operators are resolved, ***not*** when operands are evaluated. The latter is basically [***undefined***<sup>[PHP.net]</sup>](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61188#1330283084)</sup>

Comment: The parentheses did the job. Many thanks for helping me out, phantOm.