# PHP nested IF ELSE Short hand

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I'm trying to display a correct results based on the value of the variable but I'm using a short hand,

I have tried the following but its seems to ignore the first check even if the value is correct.

```
(!empty($national_ID_number)) ? 
    $national_ID_number : 
    (!empty($foreign_ID_number)) ?
        $foreign_ID_number  : 
        $temporal_permit_number)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly post the var dump of all  the variables used?

Comment: Short-hand if / else syntax is not obvious when using multiple conditions. They don't simply go left to right as you would expect. In this case, I'd recommend using standard if / else conditions. Otherwise, you need to use brackets to force the precedence of each condition to what you expect it to be.

Comment: Good lord.  Don't write code like this--it makes your fellow humans' eyes bleed.  Break it out to two nested if()s.  The ternary operator is good for one item per segment only max (not technically, but as a practical matter).

Comment: If you need to do more than a simple `if / else` with ternary then I strongly suggest that you swap over to using proper if / else structure as the ternary operator very quickly becomes hard to read / understand. (And readability is just as important (if not more) as "compact" code is).

Answer (score 2):

It's populating correctly for me with this code, you seem to have added additional bracket.

```
$national_ID_number = '';
$foreign_ID_number = 2;
$temporal_permit_number = 3;
$finalID = (!empty($national_ID_number)) ? $national_ID_number : (!empty($foreign_ID_number ) ? $foreign_ID_number  : $temporal_permit_number);
echo $finalID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went for a bit deep research - apparently each condition needs to be inside brackets and the below fix works fine.

```
(!empty($national_ID_number)) ? 
    $national_ID_number : 
    ((!empty($foreign_ID_number)) ?
        $foreign_ID_number  : 
        $temporal_permit_number));
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546627/php-if-else-shorthand-notation-multiple-conditions) and [PHP Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#language.operators.precedence)

Comment: *I just went for a bit deep research* That is something which you should do before you ask a question.